# Error when trying to submit app: No matching provisional profiles found

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I am trying to submit my app to the App Store however I am having issues with Provisioning Profiles.

When I click Submit after having archived the app, I receive the error:

No matching provisional profiles found - None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specific entitlements: applications-identifier, beta-reports-active, keychain-access-groups.

Here is my settings (I have the both the same settings in build settings in both the project and the target):

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem by changing the Architectures setting. I assume this was just a problem with Architectures/Valid Architectures being incompatible with one another.

Comment: which Valid Architectures did you have, and what are you using now? I have same issue as you and I am using "arm64, armv7, armv7s"

Comment: I just made sure that all Architectures in the "Architectures" setting appear in the "Valid Architectures" setting. Originally, I was missing one of them in "Valid Architectures".

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that a tool I was using for image resize got into the images resources that the app was bundling up. So, whilst it happily build and archived all the .png's and this rogue .app the app store barfed on it.

In the end, looking at the console log gave me the clue I needed. As soon as that file was taken out the warnings about applications-identifier, beta-reports-active and keychain-access-groups.